# Access the same table, different parameters

Tags: mysql, join

I'm making a client management database, I have a table called Dates that can access to Customer and Employee and both can access to Data, where the personal info is saved, how can I access twice to Data?

Dates Table

```
--------------------------------------
id    fk_idCustomers    fk_idEmployee
--------------------------------------
1     1               2
```

Customers Table

```
-------------------
id    fk_idData
-------------------
1     1
```

Employee Table

```
-------------------
id    fk_idData
-------------------
2     2
```

Data Table

```
------------------------
id    Name    LastName
------------------------
1     John      Doe
2     John1      Doe1
```

I want to have both, employee and customer names

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Tried anything?

Comment: Not sure what your Dates table is for and as it does not contain any dates maybe another name for it would be more informative as to its use

Comment: 'how can I access twice to Data' - join twice. And what do you want your output to look like.

Comment: I don't know what to try

Comment: @RiggsFolly it hast more things, but it doesn't matter for what I'm asking for

Comment: @P.Salmon I want Customer's name and the employee's name

Comment: On the same row, on separate rows, with or without some indication that the name is a customer or an employee, customer first employee second - What you want as an outcome dictates how you achieve it..

Comment: @P.Salmon Different rows, Customer has data id 1 and Employee has data id 2

Answer (score 0):

I think your question needs a bit more thought but you can get something by simple joins and union

```
drop table if exists dates,customers,employees,data;
create table Dates 
(id  int,  fk_idCustomers int,   fk_idEmployee int);
insert into dates values
(1   ,  1   ,            2);

create table Customers 
(id int,   fk_idData int);
insert into customers values
(1  ,   1),
(1  ,   3);

create table employees
(id  int,  fk_idData int);
insert into employees values
(2  ,   2);

create table Data 
(id int,   Name varchar(20),   LastName varchar(20));
insert into data values
(1   ,  'John'    ,  'Doe'),
(2   ,  'John1'   ,  'Doe1'),
(3   ,  'John3'   ,  'Doe3');

select d.id,d.name,d.lastname 
from   dates
join   customers c on c.id = dates.fk_idcustomers
join   data d on d.id = c.fk_iddata
union all
select d.id,d.name,d.lastname 
from   dates
join   employees e on e.id = dates.fk_idemployee
join   data d on d.id = e.fk_iddata
;

+------+-------+----------+
| id   | name  | lastname |
+------+-------+----------+
|    1 | John  | Doe      |
|    3 | John3 | Doe3     |
|    2 | John1 | Doe1     |
+------+-------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I was asking for something like
id name(customer) lastname(customer) name(Empleyee) lastname(Employee)

Comment: Sry, I'm getting use to StackOverflow

Comment: I re read what you wrote to me and I find a way to solve it, thanks!

Comment: @Joaquin Barco its ok to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer doing:

```
select 
    data.nombre , 
    data.apellido , 
    dates.documentacion,
    d.nombre,
    d.apellido
from 
    dates
inner join customers on dates.idCliente = customers.id 
inner join data on customers.idDatos = data.id
inner join employees on dates.idUsuario = employees.id
inner join dates d on employees.idDatos = d.id
;

+------+-------+----------+-------+----------+
| id   | name  | lastname | name  | lastname |
+------+-------+----------+-------+----------+
|    1 | John  | Doe      | John1 | Doe1     |
+------+-------+----------+-------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```